# $L_1$ norm of matrix and $L_{1,1}$ norm of multiplication with orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthonormal

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be any real matrix and let $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ be a matrix whose columns are orthonormal.

Is it true that
$$ \left| \left| A\right| \right|_1 \leq \left| \left| AV\right| \right|_{1,1}?$$

If so, how can it be proved?

Please advise.

P.s. the $L_{p,q}$-norm can be found [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#L2,1_and_Lp,q_norms), and $\left| \left| A \right| \right|_1 = \sup_{\left| \left| x \right| \right|_1 = 1} \left| \left| Ax\right| \right|_1$.

Comment: what type of norm is the  $\left\lVert A \right\rVert_1$ ?

Comment: I have edited the question in light of your comment.